# How to set ResultsTransformer of an IndexQuery object

Tags: ravendb

I am working on a RavenDB query on a type that is built in run time so I can't use generic methods like Query<>. I have to do this using DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Query something like this :

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Query("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", new IndexQuery{Query = "Tag : MyDocuments"},null);
```

So far so good unless this way I am getting `Json` objects and I want to transform them into another type.I realized that `IndexQuery` has a `ResultsTransformer` property but I don't know how to use it and couldn't find any documentation for this particular use of `IndexQeury` neither. 
So the question is how I can transform the results into another type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ResultsTransformer  property of the IndexQuery

**UPDATE**

To use ResultsTransformer  property of IndexQuery one should create a ResultTransformer using [AbstractResultTransformerCreationTask](http://codeofrob.com/entries/ravendb-resulttransformers---a-new-way-of-looking-at-things.html) or [DocumentStore.DatabaseCommand.PutTransformer](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/databasecommands) (that accept a raw string to create a transformer) then he can set ResultsTransformer  property of the IndexQuery to the name of this transformer.

Comment: OK I get it.As far as I understand ResultTransformers do the trick in server side but I want to be able to convert the returning JSON to a specific type in my code thus I think I can't use ResultTransformers like this.Any other solution ?